# .net HttpClient "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted"

Tags: .net, httpclient, tls1.2

I am trying to make an HTTPrequest using HttpClient on .net6. The server I am calling requires a client certificate (p12) to be send alongside the request. The implementantion is the following:

```
     _handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        _handler.ClientCertificates.Add(
            new X509Certificate2(
                Convert.FromBase64String(_configurations.ClientCertificateData),
                _configurations.ClientCertificatePassword
            )
        );

        _client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(_handler);
```

Then making the request.
The error I am getting is:

*"The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted."*

First, what's that meaning? Is the client. Which certificate is not trusted? By who?
How can I solve this problem? At least, can I?

Comment: That's most likely the server's certificate which is not being trusted by your client machine. What certificate does it have, is it self-signed, or who is the isssuer?